# Multiple JSON files in one request from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two different codes for two different URL to fetch data. Code is as below :

```
Code 1 :
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var xmlHttp;
  function parseBoolean(value) {
    return (typeof value === "undefined") ? false : value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").toLowerCase() === "true";
  }
  function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  }
  function call_post(){
    createXMLHttpRequest();
  var vosRequest = new Object();

    vosRequest.accounts = new Array(1);
    vosRequest.accounts[0] = new Object();
    vosRequest.accounts[0] = document.getElementById("accounts").value;




    xmlHttp.open("POST", "http://..../GetCustomer", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = showResult;
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(vosRequest));
    document.getElementById("postText").innerHTML = "<br>Request Format: " + JSON.stringify(vosRequest) + "</br>";
    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "";
  }
  function showResult(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
      if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "<br>Response Format: " + xmlHttp.responseText + "</br>";
    document.body.scrollTop=document.body.scrollHeight;

var json = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
document.getElementById('id01').innerHTML = json.infoCustomers[0].infoCustomerAdditional.linkMan;
document.getElementById('id02').innerHTML = json.infoCustomers[0].account;
document.getElementById('id03').innerHTML = json.infoCustomers[0].name;
var num = json.infoCustomers[0].money;
var n = num.toFixed(3);
document.getElementById('id04').innerHTML = n;
var d = new Date(json.infoCustomers[0].validTime);
d = d.toGMTString();
document.getElementById('id05').innerHTML = d;
        }
    }
  }

</script>


Code 2:

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var xmlHttp;
  function parseBoolean(value) {
    return (typeof value === "undefined") ? false : value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").toLowerCase() === "true";
  }
  function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  }
  function call_post(){
    createXMLHttpRequest();
  var vosRequest = new Object(); 
  if(document.getElementById("checkbox_account").checked){
    vosRequest.account = document.getElementById("account").value;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("checkbox_areaCode").checked){
    vosRequest.areaCode = document.getElementById("areaCode").value;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("checkbox_period").checked){
    vosRequest.period = parseFloat(document.getElementById("period").value);
  }
  if(document.getElementById("checkbox_beginTime").checked){
    vosRequest.beginTime = document.getElementById("beginTime").value;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("checkbox_endTime").checked){
    vosRequest.endTime = document.getElementById("endTime").value;
  }
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "http://.../GetReportCustomerLocationFee", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = showResult;
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(vosRequest));
    document.getElementById("postText").innerHTML = "<br>Request Format: " + JSON.stringify(vosRequest) + "</br>";
    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "";
  }
  function showResult(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
      if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "<br>Response Format: " + xmlHttp.responseText + "</br>";
        document.body.scrollTop=document.body.scrollHeight;
        var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
        var json = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
          //txt += ""
            for (x=0;x<json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees.length;x++) {
                txt += "<tr><td>" + json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].areaCode + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].areaName + "</td>";
                json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].totalFee = json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].totalFee.toFixed(3);
                txt += "<td>" + json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].totalFee + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].totalTime + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].totalSuiteFee + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + json.infoReportCustomerLocationFees[x].totalSuiteFeeTime + "</tr></td>";
            }
           // txt += "</table>" 
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = txt;

      }
    }
  }
  function load(){
  document.getElementById("account").value = "ABC";
  document.getElementById("areaCode").value = "1";
  document.getElementById("period").value = "7";
  document.getElementById("beginTime").value = "20170828";
  document.getElementById("endTime").value = "20170903";

  }
</script>
```

Both the codes are in two different html files and as an individual, both runs fine and fetches data.

I want to fetch the data of both the url in one html, i.e. I want to merge both the files and retreive data of both the request in single HTML file. 
Can u suggest how can i do it? I have searched on stackoverflow but not able to find the right solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does response structure is same for both requests ?

Comment: yes. response structure is same, only some variables are more or less

Comment: I have solved the question myself using jquery. If anyone interested to know the solution, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, can you post your solution in answer please.